# CodeIgniter - how to transfer array from controller to model and to controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been learning CodeIgniter for 5 days. Now I would like to write a simple permission function.

My controller:

```
function index(){
    $userID=$this->session->userdata('userID');
    $data['user_data']=$this->user->get_user_data($userID);
    $user_type=$user_data['user_type'];
    if($user_type <=10){
        redirect(base_url().'users/login');
    } else {
         //POBIERANIE DANYCH UŻYTKOWNIKA DO TABLICY $user_data
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('topMenu',$data);
        $this->load->view('sideBar');
        $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

My model:

```
function get_user_data($userID){
    $this->db->select()->from('users')->where('userID',$userID);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query -> first_row('array');
}
```

In a view I can use `<?=$user_data['user_type'] ?>`but when I use `$user_data['user_type']` in controller the following error appears:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: user_type
>
> Filename: controllers/dashboard.php

Please help me. I'd like to get `user_type` from MySQL and compare with value to grant or refuse access to same page.

Regards.

Comment: Try it with `$user_type = $data['user_data']['user_type'];`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! CodeIgniter is the best.

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in your controller. You are assuming that when you assign `$data['user_data']=$this->user->get_user_data($userID)` , it will magically turn into a variable in the controller. This is not the case. In your controller, you pretty much treat things as plain old precdural php. Meaning that if you assign `$data['whatever'] = whatever`, then all youre doing is making `$data` a variable that holds an array. Therefore, if you want to retrieve any information from `$data`, then you need to specify the array keys.

So in the end, in order to fix your problem. I would change this:

```
function index(){
    $userID = this->session->userdata('userID');
    $data['user_data'] = $this->user->get_user_data($userID);
    $user_type = $user_data['user_type'];
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
function index(){
    $userID = this->session->userdata('userID');
    $data['user_data'] = $this->user->get_user_data($userID);
    $user_type = $data['user_data']['user_type'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your controller to this code in bottom. this error because you not send variable to views.

```
    function index(){
    $userID=$this->session->userdata('userID');
    $user_data =    $this->user->get_user_data($userID);
    $data['user_data']['user_id']= $userID;
    $data['user_data']['user_type']=$user_data['user_type'];
    if($user_type <=10){
        redirect(base_url().'users/login');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('topMenu',$data);
        $this->load->view('sideBar');
        $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

model change to

```
function get_user_data($userID){
    $this->db->select()->from('users')->where('userID',$userID);
    $query=$this->db->get()->row_array();
    return $query;
}
```

i hope it is work.